# Install MacOs Mojave (Only Bootcamp partition)

Tags: macos, mojave

I was given a Mac Book Pro (Retina) with BootCamp and then realized it was the only partition, so I don't have a MacOs in my Mac machine!!! 
Considering that, what's the easiest way to install a MacOs?

Comment: What year is the Mac? What version of Windows? I ask this because if you truly only have one partition, the the machine must be fairly old. If so, then you probably can not install Mojave.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/539607/create-mac-partition-in-windows) link has a good starting point. First up, you obviously need to create a mac partition on the computer. Next, you will need to find a copy of macOs (obtainable via Mac App Store by all mac users, hence you only need to find a mac owner willing to give you a copy) and convert it into a bootable USB drive. Next, you have to boot into the mac partition on your computer and install macOS via the bootable drive.